# Getting "popup closed by user" even though the user hasn't in gmail login

Tags: gmail, angular5, gmail-api

I am trying to login with gmail with angular 5 social login [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-social-login) and it is working fine for facebook but in case of gmail it is opening the gmail window and when user enters his details he is authenticated but I get error message "popup_closed_by_user" even though it is getting closed automatically.
Below is my code:

```
  public socialSignIn(socialPlatform : string) {
    let socialPlatformProvider;
    if(socialPlatform == "facebook"){
      socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
    }else if(socialPlatform == "google"){
      console.log(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
      socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
      (userData) => {
        console.log("data from fb is");
        console.log(userData);
      }
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the suggested solution in [this github forum](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/293):

> I think the issue you are facing is that the popup is blocked by the
>   browser. You should not call the grant method from within an
>   asynchronous function (i.e. the onSuccess callback). The call to grant
>   must be done synchronously after a user interaction (a click for
>   instance).

Somehow I noticed this error when using Incognito mode but not when using the regular browsing mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using '@abacritt/angularx-social-login' for social media login using Angular, the below fix worked for me. This issue happens for all the newly created Client IDs. This can be resolved by adding 'plugin_name' in the provider for Angular applications.

In app.module.ts, create an object which holds the 'plugin_name'.

```
const googleLoginOptions = {
  scope: 'profile email',
  plugin_name:'sample_login'//this can be any string
};
```

And in  providers, pass the 'googleLoginOptions' object along with the google client ID.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
        {
          provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
          useValue: {
            autoLogin: false,
            providers: [
              {
                id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
                  'YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT_ID', 
                   googleLoginOptions
                )
              }
            ],
            onError: (err) => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
        }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Now, clear the browser cache and it should be working.
For app.component.ts codes you may refer to [@abacritt/angularx-social-login- documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login)

Answer (score -1):

Add this in index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async></script>
```

I hope it is resolved

Comment: While this may or may not be correct, your answer does not explain why this solves the OPs problem.